# Sum up values from different worksheets

Tags: excel-formula

I'm building the budget template in Excel. In the Summary sheet, I want to sum columns from different worksheets by the corresponding cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B4ev.png)

In my way, I get all sheet names (by VBA code, it will automatically update when creating new worksheets), then use TEXTJOIN to have all reference cells I want in a text. It looks like this: Sheet1!$B$2,Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet3!$B$2,Sheet4!$B$2,Sheet5!$B$2,Sheet6!$B$2,Sheet7!$B$2

I guess we can have some way to put that text in SUM function in Excel to sum up all reference cells value, but I haven't found how to do that yet.

If anyone can have a look and give me a solution, it's much appreciated.

Thank you as always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood the question you can do like this in reference cell:

```
  =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet7!C2)
  =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet7!C3)
  =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet7!C3)
  =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet7!C5)
  =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet7!C6)
     --------
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gretal. Your formulas are worked if Sheet1 is sitting in the 1st position, and Sheet7 is sitting in the last position (All other sheets have to be put between Sheet1 and Sheet7).
Also, in the case I need to add more sheets, I have to manually adjust, right?

Comment: welcome, yeah you can adjust.

Comment: Is there anyway to get "Sheet1:Sheet7" by INDIRECT function or some things else.

Comment: this is the way i often use.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @gretal.